# jQuery Menu Item Hover Function

Tags: jquery, sprite

I am working on an animated jQuery menu using [Spritely](http://spritely.net) the problem I have is that the animation appears not to be very smooth at all. Very stuttery. Ideally what I'd like to do is the user mouses over, Then mouses out but when they mouse out the frames stop at that frame and a mouse over again will replay this. However the animation effect appears a little stuttery.

Wonder if anyone can help me on this one.

I've made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ByYSZ/) of it to play and tweak

Thanks

Comment: It looks good in IE9 but yes a little slow in IE8. Please check the browser compatibility of the sprite plug-in that you are using

Comment: Seems to be slow-ish in FireFox too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below snippet work as expected, if I didn't misunderstand id

```
$("#access .menu-header ul li#menu-item-27 a").hover(function() {
        $("#access .menu-header ul li#menu-item-27 a").sprite({
            fps: 12, 
            no_of_frames: 9,
            play_frames: 9,
        }).spStart();
},function(){
   $("#access .menu-header ul li#menu-item-27 a").spStop(true);            
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I used instead of spStop. I used .destroy(); It seemed to prevent any real jerky animations and any issues on that.

Comment: Destroying is also a good idea, for performance reasons you may not think of destroying and recreating the animation every time. That's why I have just used stop.